# Is it possible to load a class from workflow-plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I would like to load a groovy script containing a class and then use the class in the caller script.

Something like this:

```
load 'Email.groovy'
Email email = new Email('Subject', 'me@me.me')
email.send()
```

Is this currently possible using `load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CPS Global library](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/cps-global-lib/README.md) is designed exactly for that.